# Will I be able to broadcast unto 32 bytes of data using bluetooth (Not BLE)?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a feature in the app I'm developing. It requires broadcasting of data. Now I have implemented the functionality to advertise the data using the support of new BLE feature. I want this app to be legacy supportive. I want this feature to be usable by broader set of devices (Even devices without BLE & below android 5.0). Can it be done using classic bluetooth. If no, why not? If yes, how to do that?

Thanks,

Kedar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send serial data via Bluetooth to an unspecified device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501805/how-to-send-serial-data-via-bluetooth-to-an-unspecified-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we know that Bluetooth 5 can advertise data more than you described 32 bytes.

However for classic Bluetooth, it may not possible since there are no advertisement mechanism at classic Bluetooth and even for CSB(Connectionless Slave Broadcast), I wonder there are not too much device support it.

One work around method would be you can set your parameters to the Bluetooth local name dynamically...... once your classic device  searched the device can parse the name. how tricky it is.