# How to set iBeacon message id (UUID, Major, Minor) in android (for own mobile device) programatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, ibeacon-android

My app has to broadcast via Bluetooth an iBeacon message. The iBeacon message should be fixed in a particular UUID, Major and Minor.

How can it be done without using any 3rd party applications? (I'm okay with libraries, I just don't want the user to need another app to use this app. I prefer this app to be self-dependent when being used).

EDIT : I've built it with only google ble docs and any other libraries haven't been used. Though, I'm open to implement any suggestions that make it work.

Comment: Have you seen this: [Can an Android device act as an iBeacon?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19602913/295004)

Comment: thank you @MorrisonChang, this is exactly what's needed. I wish I could upvote this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html) which is totally free and open source.

1. Add this to your build.gradle dependencies:

   ```
    dependencies {
       implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2+'
    }
   ```
2. Paste this code to start your transmitter:

   ```
    Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
       .setId1("2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6")
       .setId2("1")
       .setId3("2")
       .setManufacturer(0x004c)
       .setTxPower(-59)
       .build();
    BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
       .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
    BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new 
    BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser); 
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
   ```

If you really want to not compile against a third-party library, you are welcome to copy the source code for the BeaconTransmitter, but that's harder to do:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconTransmitter.java

Comment: thank you Mr. Young, I did exactly this from Morrison Chang's suggestion above. Almost the entirety of my project is built from your answers from different posts all over SO