# Beacon show it's present or ranging even if, Beacon Battery is removed, what to do, to remove this bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibeacon

For StartMonitoring iBeacon my code is

```
-(void)startMonitoringForRegionWithUUID:(NSString*)UUID
{
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion= [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:UUID] identifier:UUID];
    beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
    beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;
    //[self stopMonitoringForRegionWithUUID:UUID];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:beaconRegion];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
   NSLog(@"Number Of Beacons=%d",beacons.count); // show count for removed cell beacon too. there is no any other beacon with same UUID.
}
```

Above mentioned delegate methods show, false beacon. Even if, beacon battery is removed from beacon. Beacons array having present of those beacon. It happens when I run iPhone or iPad for almost 4-5 hours in beacon region.
After restarting device,when `didRangeBeacon` callback happens it works fine. My question is, Why restarting does wonder? And what to do so I can avoid getting wrong beacon in callback method `didRangeBeacons`?

Note:- i am using Kontak iBeacon.

Comment: I have never witnessed behavior like this.  Please post your code, as I suspect there may be a logic error.

Comment: After you remove the battery, what do you see in the log for "Number Of Beacons=..."?

Comment: i have kontak's three beacons, if one of beacon don't have battery, nevertheless output is  "Number Of Beacons=3"

Comment: I cannot explain what you report.  I have never witnessed this behavior.

Comment: ok, but thanks for your reply. whenever this scenario happens it's RSSI value is 0, so i am not considering those beacons whose RSSI is 0. by using this it's working fine for my app logic.

Comment: I am seeing this issue as well.  I can sometimes the problem by upgrading the app while it is running in the background (or by using Xcode to relaunch the app).  In my case, I only test with 1 beacon and I continue to see the single beacon even though the battery has been removed.  The reported RSSI is -60.  (Note: Also using a Kontakt.io beacon.)  Only solution is to restart the device.  iPhone 4s iOS 8.0.2